# Custom Sequential Workflow creates 10 items for 1 event in Calendar

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-enterprise

I had created a Custom Sequential Workflow in Visual Studio 2010 which runs when any Event is added in Calendar List. I have created a Custom Column named "Sequence". Now when I create any event in calender, Workflow Starts and makes 10 additional entries for same Data. What should I do to prevent it from creating 10 additional Entries?

[image]

This is How it looks when i create a new Item.

My Code is as below.

```
            SPWeb web = workflowProperties.Web;
            SPList Calendar = workflowProperties.List;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            Random  randomNum = new Random();
            SPListItem calendarItem = Calendar.Items.Add();
            calendarItem["Sequence"] = randomNum.Next();
            calendarItem.SystemUpdate();
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: Why do you use `AllowUnsafeUpdates`?

Comment: First it was returning error that's why I used Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates but when error was gone I forget to remove it. There is no need of it. I removed it and then also code Worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
   I tried this and it worked.

    SPWeb web = workflowProperties.Web;
    SPList Calendar = workflowProperties.List;
    Random  randomNum = new Random();
    SPListItem calendarItem = workflowProperties.Item;
    calendarItem["Sequence"] = randomNum.Next();
    calendarItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your workflow becomes recursive.
If you update the item you could try using [`SPListItem.SystemUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx).

Comment: SPListItem.SystemUpdate is Not Working.. It Shows same result..:(